# Como listar itens por mês no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso que seja listado ativos que tenham algo previsto por período, no caso preciso que eles me tragam por mês, deixarei um exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho aqui um relatório em que trago um ativo que me retorna tudo, porém necessito que ele me retorne somente o que está previsto por mês, abaixo a query.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT V_AssetParentAssetCL.asset, AssetWorkProcedure.equipment, Asset.equipmentType, AssetWorkProcedure.workProcedure, AssetWorkProcedure.intervalType,AssetWorkProcedure.dateInterval, AssetWorkProcedure.nextWODate, CONVERT(VARCHAR,AssetWorkProcedure.dateInterval) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1),(CASE WHEN AssetWorkProcedure.intervalType = '2' THEN 'M' ELSE 'D' END)) as period, 

    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-01-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-01' OR initDate < '" + year +"-01-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as JAN, 
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-02-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-02' OR initDate < '" + year +"-02-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as FEV, 
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-03-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-03' OR initDate < '" + year +"-03-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as MAR, 
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-04-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-04' OR initDate < '" + year +"-04-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as ABR, 
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-05-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-05' OR initDate < '" + year +"-05-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as MAI,
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-06-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-06' OR initDate < '" + year +"-06-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as JUN,
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-07-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-07' OR initDate < '" + year +"-07-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as JUL,
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-08-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-08' OR initDate < '" + year +"-08-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as AGO,
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-09-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-09' OR initDate < '" + year +"-09-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as [SET],
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-10-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-10' OR initDate < '" + year +"-10-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as [OUT],
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-11-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-11' OR  initDate < '" + year +"-11-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as NOV,
    CASE WHEN (intervalType = '1' OR DATEDIFF(MONTH,initDate,'" + month +"-12-01')%dateInterval = 0) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),initDate,121) =  '" + year +"-12' OR initDate < '" + year +"-12-01') THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END as DEZ

    from AssetWorkProcedure 
    LEFT JOIN V_AssetParentAssetCL ON AssetWorkProcedure.asset = V_AssetParentAssetCL.asset
    LEFT JOIN Asset  ON AssetWorkProcedure.asset = Asset.asset
    LEFT JOIN WorkOrder   ON WorkOrder.asset = Asset.asset
```

Como faço para esse ativo me retornar somente o que está previsto por mês? Por exemplo, no mes de dezembro de 2019 está previsto a troca de um equipamento, ou mês de maio está previsto a mudança de atividade.

Comment: Acrescente no texto de seu problema a descrição da tabela (colunas etc). Por exemplo, explique sobre as colunas intervalType, month, initDate, dateInterval.

Answer (score -1):

Tente agrupar os dados do seu select:

```
    SELECT  YEAR(DataReferencia)
           ,MONTH(DataReferencia)
           ,count(*) from Tabela
  GROUP BY  MONTH(DataReferencia)
           ,year(DataReferencia)
```

Comment: Olá, Edson! Você pode utilizar o código  em sua resposta. Não utilize imagem(print) do código e sim o código puro. Saudações.

Comment: Modificado @FabianoMonteiro =D